# $E(X_1|X_1+X_2=k)$ increases with $k$?

Tags: probability-theory

$X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent, but they may not follow the same distribution. I want to know whether $E(X_1|X_1+X_2=k)$ increases with $k$. I guess this is correct, but is there a proof or counter example? Thank you very much!

Comment: Assume $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $X$ uniform on $\{0,1\}$, $Y$ uniform on $\{0,2\}$, then $E(X\mid X+Y=1)=1$ while $E(X\mid X+Y=2)=0$. For examples with densities, use convolution with gaussian random variables with small variances.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not true. Suppose $X_1$ has uniform distribution over $\{0,1,2\}$ and $X_2$ has uniform distribution over $\{0,2,3\}$

$E(X_1 | X_1+X_2=0) = 0$

$E(X_1 | X_1+X_2=1) = 1$

$E(X_1 | X_1+X_2=2) = 1$

$E(X_1 | X_1+X_2=3) = \frac{1}{2}$

$E(X_1 | X_1+X_2=4) = \frac{3}{2}$

$E(X_1 | X_1+X_2=5) = 2$